# A python script that outputs windows batch file.

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, output

I am working on a python script that will walk through a large collection of .py files and write out individual .bat files that can be called upon to run these scripts.

I understand typical python output

```
directory = 'c:/'
OPATH = open(str(directory) + 'output_file.txt', 'w')
```

However if I try to do output_file.bat I receive an error, and it won't let me write out to it.

What I would like written in the batch files. 
[Creating a BAT file for python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571244/creating-a-bat-file-for-python-script)

Is there any documentation on how to write out other kinds of files with python? I would also be interested in having a python script generate .c files as well.

Comment: The error message is always worth a look, could you copy-paste it inside your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using [`os.path.join()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join). Your error was merely trivial, don't worry.

```
import os

directory = 'C:/'
with open(os.path.join(directory, 'output_file.bat'), 'w') as OPATH:
    OPATH.writelines(['@echo off', 
                      'c:\python27\python.exe c:\somescript.py %*', 
                      'pause'])
```

This provides a cross-platform solution to your problem. Although your error was due to a missing `/`, you should not hardcode this. This is the best way to join two paths and thus solve your problem.

Comment: I'm an idiot, sorry its been a long day in the office. Only other difference is the output is going to be 'output_file.bat'

Comment: @AlienAnarchist In which case you can just change the `.txt` to a '.bat' in the code as shown in my edits. Python can edit this file type just fine.