# Automatically run a Python program when the system boots

Tags: python, linux, windows

Is there a way to make the Python program to run in background when the system boots?

(on windows and linux systems)

Comment: On what OS? Windows, Linux, MacOS?

Comment: win and linux. it would be very helpful :)

Comment: I would take a look at systemd services on Linux. You can possibly do the same thing on Windows if you have WSL, but I have not tried it.

Comment: in Linux you can use cronjobs, in windows powershell or task manager.

Comment: maybe but i want to do it remotely so it is easy for win 10 but not for linux

Comment: It should be easy to do it remotely for Linux as well assuming you can SSH in and you have `sudo` privileges

Comment: does not matter how you want to do it, you can set your user crontab file in a remote machine via ssh.

Comment: hmm yes i will try it thank you guys

Comment: This question has been asked and answered everywhere. Possible duplicate of [Run Python script at startup in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24518522/608639), [Run Python Script on OS boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/817011), [How to start a python file while Windows starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4438020/608639), [Run a program at start-up on python in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31130960/608639), etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Can Add Your Script In Startup!

Here is For Window 10

1) First Open Your File Explorer!

Then Paste This Address `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp`

Here is the ScreenShot!

[image]

in that folder paste your script!

Here is another Screenshot!

[image]

It Will Automatically Start Your Script When Your System Boot

Another Thing You Can Try Task Scheduler!

For More Details Here is the website that can help you!

https://tunecomp.net/add-program-to-startup-windows-10/

Answer (score 1):

On linux in a terminal:

```
crontab -e
```

then add the following to the file:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/your/python/script.py
```

Comment: yes we can always crontab but setting it in a remote system is difficult

Comment: @JOKER What do you mean? You don't need root, it will run as the user you make it with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If your OS is linux then you can try supervisor. Otherwise you can just directly create a service in linux for your python file which you wants to run and then enable it for auto start when system boots up.

Comment: but it becomes difficult to set this up on a host machine which i dont have complete access .

Comment: implementing this solution need sudo access of machine, without that you can not achieve this as per my knowledge.

Comment: yes i will use the ssh shell for this. thanks for the tips tho :)

Answer (score 0):

**This solution is specially for linux system**

- Place the script into /etc/rc.local **Scripts there run as root when the system starts**

> Add your script as `python /path/to/script.py &`
>
> so add **python /path/to/script.py &** to **/etc/rc.local**

[For More Info Refer this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49626/purpose-and-typical-usage-of-etc-rc-local/49635#49635)