# Execute Python script in batch file with params

Tags: windows, python-2.7, batch-file, virtualenv

I tried using the accepted answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571244/creating-a-bat-file-for-python-script), but it isn't working.  Also, how would I add params?  I'm using virtualenv and trying to activate that environment and then run my script.

**Current Batch File - Does not execute last line**

```
cd\
cd c:\mydir\scripts\
activate.bat
c:\mydir\scripts\python.exe c:\mydir\scripts\myscript.py %*
```

**Desired batch file with params - Script accepts a 2D array**

```
cd\
cd c:\mydir\scripts\
activate.bat
c:\mydir\scripts\python.exe c:\mydir\scripts\myscript.py [[p1,p2,p3,p4],[p1,p2,p3,p4]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batch files are funny. If you execute a batch file from within another batch file by just specifying the batch file name, as you would from the command line, the first batch file gets terminated. To prevent this, [`CALL`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) the second batch file from the first - in your example batch file (specifically, the desired one), change the line that reads

```
activate.bat
```

to read

```
call activate.bat
```

and you should be OK.

Comment: Worked perfect! Wish I could give you a thousand up votes for this lol. It's been driving me crazy for days.