# Batch File for Python Script that reads data from a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, batch-file

```
@echo off
Python exe path Python Script.py
pause
```

This is my batch file, But the error is that my Script.py reads data from a CSV file. How can I encounter that in my batch file?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking. Is the error with the batch file or the python script? If it's with the python script, please upload some code so we can see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a BAT file for python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571244/creating-a-bat-file-for-python-script)