# Start Anaconda and perform Python calculations via BAT

Tags: python, batch-file, anaconda

Python scripts are great for many things, but sometimes I just need to open a command line and do basic calculations. It would be nice not to have to run Anaconda, then start Python, then import the math package, then define basic constants (e.g. `Na = 6.022e23`) every time I need to calculate something simple.

Therefore, I have tried writing a batch file to run Anaconda, start Python, import the math package, and define constants. These lines in my BAT code will start Anaconda and Python:

```
call C:\Users\Chris\Miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\Chris\Miniconda3
python
```

Unfortunately, any lines I add after this in the BAT code are ignored. I would be grateful for any recommendations to make this work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571244/creating-a-bat-file-for-python-script

Comment: look at Michael Villani's answer on that thread

Comment: If you want to run another command, before closing the python executable, try `start`. e.g. `start python`. Please open a Command Prompt window and enter `start /?` to read its help information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
call "C:\Users\Chris\Miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" "C:\Users\Chris\Miniconda3"
python -i -c "import math; Na = 6.022e23"
```

This code may suit your need if the Python code is compact. It will `import` and assign constants as arguments to Python. Use `;` to separate Python code lines instead of newline character(s).

The `-i` is to enter inspection mode and `-c` allows Python code to be the following argument.

Based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59248942/9012170) by Michael Villani:

```python
 @echo off
rem = r'''
:: From here and on, write any Batch file syntax and it will be ignored by Python
::
:: The Batchography book by Elias Bachaalany
::
call "C:\Users\Chris\Miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" "C:\Users\Chris\Miniconda3"
python -ix "%~f0" %*
exit /b
:: End of batch file commands
'''
# Anything here is interpreted by Python
del rem
import math
Na = 6.022e23
```

Recommend to use a raw string literal so that `\` does not need to be escaped for the batch-file code.

Both concepts cause inspection mode `-i` after the Python code has executed. Use `exit()` or `quit()` to exit the inspection mode.

So you can use the interactive prompt and enter your math.

> ```python
> >>> Na
> 6.022e+23
> >>> 3+2
> 5
> >>>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
rem = """
:: From here and on, write any Batch file syntax and it will be ignored by Python
:: 
:: The Batchography book by Elias Bachaalany
::
python -x "%~f0" %*
exit /b %errorlevel%
:: End of batch file commands
"""
# Anything here is interpreted by Python
import platform
import sys
print("Hello world from Python %s!\n" % platform.python_version())
print("The passed arguments are: %s" % sys.argv[1:])
```

http://lallouslab.net/2017/06/12/batchography-embedding-python-scripts-in-your-batch-file-script/

Comment: Thanks, @Dhruv. Unfortunately this code does not give me what I need, which is an open terminal (with Python started and some Python lines already run) that I can use to do basic math. When I try to put the above code in a batch file, the resulting window immediately closes.