# how to pause a program until a button is pressed

Tags: python, py2exe

I am using py2exe to make executable.
I want to know how to pause the program until a button is pressed..  just like we do in C using `system("pause");`

As the program terminates automatically in windows, I need this tool.

*Is there anything better than py2exe which does similar work ?*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make python to wait for a pressed key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983354/how-do-i-make-python-to-wait-for-a-pressed-key)

Comment: `system("pause")` is pretty much the worst idea ever in C.

Comment: @Wooble: Then what would you recommend.. using scanf() is a better idea?

Comment: `getc` is probably the best bet; `system("pause")` will only work on systems with a `pause` command (so, basically, Windows), and it's completely ridiculous to hand over control to an external program to do something as simple as waiting for user input.  You could actually use `subprocess.call("pause")` in Python, would do the same thing and be just as ridiculous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use raw_input in Python2, or input in Python 3

```
raw_input("Press Enter to terminate.")
```

Answer (score 4):

A quick code snippet to handle both Python 2 and 3:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
python2 = sys.version_info[0] == 2
if python2:
    raw_input("Press ENTER to continue.")
else:
    input("Press ENTER to continue.")
```

Answer (score -2):

import os

Then in your code

os.system("pause")

Comment: @binarysubstrate, I thought it was only needed on Windows. I just assumed that Linux users didn't start terminal scripts from a GUI, so it wouldn't need to create a temporary terminal.