# What is the Python Equivalent of Batch's PAUSE function

Tags: python, batch-file

What is the Python Equivalent of Batch's

```
PAUSE
```

function? The program shall wait for the user to press a key before continuation.

Comment: What does `PAUSE` do?

Comment: It waits for the user to press a key before continuation

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make python to wait for a pressed key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983354/how-do-i-make-python-to-wait-for-a-pressed-key)

Comment: Oh... sorry That wouldn't have been my first search term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pause for a few seconds, take a look at [`time.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep).

To wait for input (you can discard it if you wish), use [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) or [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).

To wait for **any** input, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1135035/948550) suggests (windows only):

```
import msvcrt as m
def wait():
    m.getch()
```

A [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16933120/948550) in the same thread suggests using an external tool if it's available (not windows), `read`:

```
os.system('read -s -n 1 -p "Press any key to continue..."')
```