# How do I read user commands in bash on the fly with python?

Tags: python, bash, terminal

I'm working on a [research project](https://gist.github.com/Skraelingjar/39092ccb8eca4c9df3c56b1e392cb5d6) and am trying to read what a user is entering into the terminal, stopping the execution while the command is evaluated, and then resuming (or closing) the session.

I found this [example in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pty.html) that opens a new session, records everything, and writes it to a file.

After cutting extras I ended up with this:

```
import os, pty

shell = os.environ.get('SHELL', 'sh')

with open('typescript', 'w') as script:
    def read(fd):
        data = os.read(fd, 1024)
        # Parse on the hash
        cmd = data.decode()
        before, sep, after = cmd.rpartition("#")
        script.write(after)
        return data

    pty.spawn(shell, read)
```

This has two problems, one is that it's reactive and the other is that it also captures any output from a given command.

When looking for another way I found this answer to [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983354/how-do-i-make-python-to-wait-for-a-pressed-key):

```
def wait_key():
''' Wait for a key press on the console and return it. '''
result = None
if os.name == 'nt':
    import msvcrt
    result = msvcrt.getch()
else:
    import termios
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()

    oldterm = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    newattr = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    newattr[3] = newattr[3] & ~termios.ICANON & ~termios.ECHO
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSANOW, newattr)

    try:
        result = sys.stdin.read(1)
    except IOError:
        pass
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, oldterm)

return result
```

I read the terminos docs and think this may be the way to go but I don't understand how to adapt it to act on the ENTER key.

EDIT: What I'm doing is evaluating the commands with a machine learning model and deciding whether or not to allow the command to execute, like preventing someone from sudo rm -rf /. This is really just a proof-of-concept and demonstration.

Is there possibly a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Trying not to actively block the main thread is a general principle in UI design. If you want the console to be open for the user to interact with at all times, you could be running your code asynchronously in [another thread](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects).

Implementing the pausing feature that you want could be done by having a lock or semaphore (see python thread api) that you would lock from the main thread to tell the worker thread to stop. A quick google search suggests that it's pretty simple to implement [stoppable threads in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python) for the case where you want to just terminate the program.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I hadn't considered spinning off a different thread. For this program the main goal is to test my back-end and the UI is not important. My primary focus is simply capturing the command `ls -al` (or any other) and making an evaluation.

Comment: Okay, like [subprocess?](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). Are you just spitting out the results back to the terminal?

Comment: Most of the answers to the second link you provided just say to use `raw_input`. `raw_input` would only return when you press enter so why are you opting for this other method of data entry?

Comment: What I'm doing is evaluating the commands with a machine learning model and deciding whether or not to allow the command to execute, like preventing someone from `sudo rm -rf /`. This is really just a proof-of-concept and demonstration.

Comment: Okay sounds like it would be really useful. So why have you decided not to just do something like `while(input=raw_input("user: ")):` `#ML code` `if itsAllGood:` `subprocess(input.split())` `else:` `#shutItDown`

Comment: My thought was to keep it a real terminal so things like tab completion, git status, and the like still worked.