# input("Press Enter to continue..."): SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python

I have a simple code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                                                                       
import sys
print (sys.version)

list = ["cat", "dog", "horse", "duck"]
for animal in list:
    if animal == "cat" or animal == "duck":
        print animal
        input("Press Enter to continue ...")
```

The output of `print (sys.version)` is

```
2.7.11 (default, Dec 19 2016, 17:44:19) 
[GCC 5.3.0]
```

However, the program crashes at line `input("Press Enter to continue ...")` upon pressing  <kbd>Enter</kbd> , indicating an error

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Why would this happen?

This question is related to [How do I make python to wait for a pressed key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983354/how-do-i-make-python-to-wait-for-a-pressed-key)

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3? In Python 2, `input()` tries to evaluate what you enter, you need to use `raw_input()` if you don't want that.

Comment: python 2: use `raw_input`

Comment: or run your script with python 3

Comment: note that all the info is in the link _you_ provided

Comment: Seriously, you should be learning Python 3. Python 2 will reach its official End Of Life in 2020.