# How do I get a shell to stay open on VBA on Excel?

Tags: python, excel, vba, shell

I'm using VBA on Excel to run a Python script. Here's what my module looks like:

```
Sub PythonButton()

RetVal = Shell("C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\myName\Desktop\test.py", 1)

End Sub
```

My command window opens up and appears to give some feedback but the window only remains for a split second. How do I get this window to stay open until, say, the user presses a key?

Comment: Add pause command

Comment: @QHarr how do I do that? I'm very new to this

Comment: I'm unsure if you can do Shell("C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\myName\Desktop\test.py" && Pause, 1)

Comment: @QHarr didn't work unfortunately :( but thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Did it error or just run through and ignore?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make python to wait for a pressed key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983354/how-do-i-make-python-to-wait-for-a-pressed-key)

Comment: @QHarr it just went through and ignored. What I ended up doing instead is using a batch file, and that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a batch file with a "pause" in it instead:

```
Sub PythonButton()

RetVal = Shell("C:\Users\myName\Desktop\start.bat", 1)

End Sub
```

I let my batch file run the python script instead.