# How to communicate two python files so one prints just before the other reads though the console (interactive)

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, spyder

what I want is something like this:
The first file just prints as soon as the 2nd has read

```
# a.py
print('pepe')
# wait till the other had read
print(23)
```

The second program uses data from the later

```
# b.py
name = input()
age = int(input())
print('Hi ' + name + ', you are ' str(age))
```

So I can see in the console:

```
Hi pepe, you are 23
```

I want to do this because, I waste a lot of time typing in the console. And I want to do it automatically.

Just in case, I browsed for this thing a long time, but no idea, that is why I decided to ask here.

Comment: I added visual studio code and spyder because those are the IDEs I have used, so an answer on those ones would be the best.

Comment: Your program isn't complete, but I made a python class making patching easy. 
[PatchBay 0.1](https://github.com/TedLyngmo/patchbay)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of different ways.

1) while True:
an infinite loop that requires you to use some sort of

```
while True:
    cmd = input("type something")
    if cmd == 'e':
        do something
    elif cmd == 'f':
        do something else
    else:
        do that last thing
```

2) input("press enter to continue")

```
input('press enter to continue')
```

Hopefully that gets you what you need...

You can also learn more here: [How do I make python to wait for a pressed key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983354/how-do-i-make-python-to-wait-for-a-pressed-key)