# MAC OS - os.system(command) display nothing

Tags: python, macos, python-idle

When I run IDLE (python 3.8) :

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system("ls")
0
>>> os.system('echo "test"')
0
>>> os.system("users")
0
>>>
```

But if i do :

```
os.system("ls > test.txt")
```

The test.txt file is created and contain the result.

I tried to reinstall and everything, nothing works...
Only if I Run python in my terminal, command works but IDLE seems better for work.

Who could help me ? Thank you

Comment: The output of `os.system()` goes directly to your terminal; Python plays no part in the process.  If you aren't running from a terminal, the output has nowhere to go.  Use the `subprocess` module to run programs in a way that lets you do something with their output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the same issue and this is what I did:

- Restart the IDLE.
- Restart my laptop.

However, the same problem persists.

My suggestion is, instead of using IDLE, why don't you use the terminal? In my case, I use iTerm.

```
$ python3.8
$ >>> import os
$ >>> os.system("ls")
```

And everything works fine.

Answer (score -1):

If you start IDLE from Terminal with
`$ python3 -m idlelib'
them output from os.system will appear in Terminal while the return value is printed in the IDLE Shell.  But I unless I were developing a Python script that uses os.system, I would just keep IDLE and Terminal both open and type the appropriate commands in each.