# how do i make my program copy the output after pressing a key?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a password generator, and now I need to make it copy the generated password when pressing the key "C", I've tried "input("press c to copy") but it didn't work.
any ideas?

```
import random

print("Welcome to the password generator")

input("press enter to generate a password : ")

def password(length):

    pw = str()

    characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqurstuvwxyz"

    numbers = "123456789"

    weird= "/?!$£*<>"

    for i in range(length):

        pw = pw + random.choice(characters) + random.choice(numbers) + random.choice(weird)

    print(pw)

    return pw


password(4)

#this's what I tried

input("press c to copy")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard-on-windows-using-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make python wait for a pressed key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983354/how-do-i-make-python-wait-for-a-pressed-key)

Answer (score 1):

install and use the [pyperclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/) library

to install:

```
pip install pyperclip
```

simple usage:

```
import pyperclip

pyperclip.copy(pw)
```

your code will be like this:

```
import random
import pyperclip

print("Welcome to the password generator")
input("press enter to generate a password : ")

def password(length):
    pw = str()
    characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqurstuvwxyz"
    numbers = "123456789"
    weird= "/?!$£*<>"

    for i in range(length):
        pw = pw + random.choice(characters) + random.choice(numbers) + random.choice(weird)

    print(pw)

    return pw


pw = password(4)
pyperclip.copy(pw)
```

The code I provided will copy the password without pressing any key.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to copy no matter what you could try:

```
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy(password(4))
```

If you wanted to wait till you hit C there are 2 ways to do this
The simple way is to hit c and then hit enter
then do an if statement if the input that came was a c
like this

```
import pyperclip
key = input("press c to copy: ") 
if key == "c":
   pyperclip.copy(password(4))
```

the other way is to use pynput to listen to all your keyboard strokes.

Comment: Note that `pyperclip` is not a part of Python's standard library, so the user needs to `pip install pyperclip` first.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Keyboard Module `pip install keyboard`

Here is an example of using it(Hope this helps)

```py
import keyboard

while True:

    if(keyboard.is_pressed('c')):
        # Do Stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

**First, import pyautogui, then add this to the bottom of your script:**

```
pyautogui.typewrite(['up'])
pyautogui.typewrite(['up'])
pyautogui.hotkey('shift','end')
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','c')
```

(This only works if you run the script with the python editor.)