# Making a python script that continues on enter

Tags: python

I was making a terminal-type program with python and I was wondering if I could make it print the next line of text after you press enter
e.g

```
 `print('this was a triumph')
 #press enter to print the next line
 print('Im making a note here, huge success!')`
```

Comment: Use `input('Press enter to print next line')`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983354/how-do-i-make-python-wait-for-a-pressed-key

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make python wait for a pressed key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983354/how-do-i-make-python-wait-for-a-pressed-key)

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```py
input('this was a triumph')
input('Im making a note here, huge success!')
```

or:

```py
print('this was a triumph')
input('Press Enter To Continue:')
print('Im making a note here, huge success!')
```