# Detect if any has been pressed in Python

Tags: python, keyboard, key, low-latency

What is a good way to detect is any key has been pressed using Python. I can detect a particular key but see no easy and fast way to detect if any key has been pressed. Currently, I am using the keyboard library in Python. Is there is any latency-free way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make python wait for a pressed key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983354/how-do-i-make-python-wait-for-a-pressed-key)

Comment: If you are on Windows, I think this can work for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/38729688/15020017