# How can I press enter to go on a new line?

Tags: python, input, enter

Say if I did:

```
print("hello")
print("nice to meet you!)
```

What I wanted it to do output is:

```
  hello
```

then you press the enter key and then it does the
`print("nice to meet you!")`.

(I am making a subtitle story type thing.)

I tried `input()` but that allows text input when I only want I to allow the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
I don't know if if could do a detect key pressed or something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make python wait for a pressed key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983354/how-do-i-make-python-wait-for-a-pressed-key)

Comment: On Windows you can use [`msvcrt.kbhit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.kbhit) to check to see if a key has been pressed (and [`msvcrt.getch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getch)) to read what key it is if it matters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try doing same

```
print ('hello')
input('Input some value: ')
print('nice to meet you!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but the easiest way to use input() function. However, you can use this function for any keyboard input

```
import keyboard as keyboard
print("Hello")

while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('Enter'):
            print("Nice to Meet You")
            break
    except:
        break
```

Comment: Note that `keyboard`is not a part of Python's standard library.

Comment: Do not forget to use pip install for it.