# Python Press Keyboard for close text file

Tags: python, logging, keyboard

In my project, I use Python module `logging` to generate execution report in a text file. My question is, how to close a report that is already open with any key on the keyboard?

I've already checked the package `keyboard` some other but they didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In general to ask user input any key, I did a quick search and found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/7bij6z/how_to_press_any_key_to_continue_in_python_34/) on reddit, the gist is that it's not easy to do because it's platform dependent, if you will be satisfied with 'press enter' instead of any key, than it's [pretty straight forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983354/how-do-i-wait-for-a-pressed-key)

Comment: I want to close a text file opened in Notepad

Comment: Is the file opened from python as well? Or does one open it from outside your script?

Comment: the file is opened with the python script in the notepad application